# KDE4: Session loses authentication priviledges

Tags: linux, kde, kde-4, networkmanager

After a few hours within a KDE session, my system services will loose their ability to retrieve sensitive information. Is there any way to fix this?

Background:

1. On startup I'll be prompted for a password after login. This is for KWallet, and its to release the wireless keys to Network Manager.
2. After some period of time (more than 1 hour) if the connection is lost, then the values cannot be retrieved again. Network Manager fails to grab the keys and throws a fit (either doesn't connect or prompts for the raw password)

This is incredibly hard to reproduce, and I'm not sure how to succinctly describe it. Where would I go about looking for log statements?

More info: On login, KWallet is requesting permissions for the "KDE Daemon." Also, the wallet icon in the toolbar remains open during the whole session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KWallet has settings to drop any after a timeout, after screensaver etc... Perhaps you have the first option set. Look under Wallet Preferences, for "Close when unused for [x] min"

Comment: That option is not enabled. The only one that is enabled is "Close when last appliaction stops using it."